# Apply function to all columns in a my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have trouble to apply my custom function to a `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": ["related-1", "related-0", "related-1"],
        "b": ["request-1", "request-0", "request-1"],
        "c": ["offer-1", "offer-0", "offer-1"],
    })

def clean_column(df, column):
    return df[column].apply(lambda x: re.sub(".*-", "", x)).astype("int64")

clean_column(df, "a") # This works
```

I want to apply this function to multiple columns:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: clean_column(df, x))
```

Error: `KeyError: 'related-1'`

Now sure what I am doing wrong here, can somebody tell me the reason this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` takes the whole column as input, not just the name. So you want:

```
def clean_column(column):
    return column.apply(lambda x: re.sub(".*-", "", x)).astype("int64")

df.apply(clean_column)
```

However, in your case, you do `apply` again for each column. In other words, you want to apply a function to all cells. That is `applymap`:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(".*-", "", x)).astype("int64")
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply your function to all columns:

```
for i in df.columns:
    clean_column(df, i)
```

Be aware that this will not update the df itself, you must change your function if you want that

Answer (score 0):

You could use actually:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(".*-", "", x)).astype("int64")
```